# Cannot build library dependent project after update to ADT 14

Tags: android, adt

In order to implement different versions of our UI we broke our program up into UI specific code and a common library project that has everything else.  Up until yesterday when I updated to ADT 14 everything was working fine.  Now I can't build.  I keep getting the error "The container 'Library Projects' references non existing library 'path to the bin folder of my common project and the name of the project.jar'

I've been all over the web and tried everything I can think of to fix this to no avail.  Can someone help me out?  I'm basically stuck at this point.

Comment: check this link it's for [known issues](http://tools.android.com/knownissues)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe you have the same issues I had when switching to the new ADT:

In my previous setup I had some resources split between the library and the main project. The library project would not compile error free on its own but only in combination with the main project which added the missing resources.

It doesn't work like this any more.

The library project must compile completely error free now. When it does the build process will create a <lib_project_name>.jar in the bin folder of the library project.

If the jar file is not created ( thus the build process of the library project failed for some reason - eg. because the changes in the R.java file (see http://tools.android.com/recent/buildchangesinrevision14 )) you will get the error message you described.

Also, I had to manually remove the <lib_project>_src from the project.

Comment: Do you know whether library may use other libraries in r14? (if all of them compiles without errors now in r13). If that won't work anymore it will break plenty of my projects.

Comment: i haven't tried that yet. but I would assume that if you don't have circular dependencies I'd say it should work.

Comment: So if I reference resources in my library that are in the main application I need to declare them again in the library for it to work?

Comment: yes. i created some dummy graphics / values as placeholder so that i see immediately if they get overwritten correctly.

Comment: one of my build errors in the library had to do with a raw file, do you know if duplicating that cause problems?

Comment: I answered my own question...it is working fine.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I've had a problem with a few different projects where I did the fixes suggested in the other answer, but they were only fixed temporarily.

Every time I reopened Eclipse or did a Clean on a project, the "Library Projects" directory would disappear, and I would have to open the project properties, remove the library, and add it again.

I solved this the hard way by creating a new project and copying everything into it.

Then I found an easy way to solve it. Right click the project, Refactor-->Rename. You can rename it back afterwards. This fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the article "Changes to Library Projects in Android SDK Tools, r14" ( http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/10/changes-to-library-projects-in-android.html ) on the Android Developers blog.

E.g. @P.Melch: "I had to manually remove the _src from the project" should be done as follows:

> To fix the project, you must remove the extraneous source folders with the following steps:
>
> - Right click source folder and choose Build Path > Remove from Build
>     path.
> - A dialog will pop up. In it, make sure to check “Also unlink the folder from the project” to completely remove the folder.

Answer (score 0):

You have to update the Android SDK in Android SDK Manager

Android SDK Tools          Intalled
Android SDK Plataforms     Installed
Android SDK Builds         Installed