# Problems building Android project after Eclipse and SDK update

Tags: android, eclipse, resources, sdk

I have just updated Eclipse, the Android SDK, and everything else that appeared updatable, via Eclipse's Help->Check for Updates and Window->Android SDK Manager.

My project consists of a main project and 2 library projects. One library project is the normal Android License library project. The other library project contains Java files that reference Android resources that it itself doesn't contain, but that are present in the main project (for example R.id.myPic is used in the library project, but is actually contained in the main project). I had no problem building and running the main project before the update.

For some reason now I cannot build the main project. The main project folder has a "subfolder" called "Library Projects", which contains a jar file for the Android Licensing, but does not show a jar for the second library project. I also have a red exclamation mark on the main project folder.

For some reason I cannot rebuild the library file together with the main project. I've tried Cleaning all projects, building one then the other, building all, restarting Eclipse, but no luck.

If I go to the project properties, then Java Build Path, then Libraries, it appears that the jar file for the library project is missing, but I cannot independently create a jar file for this since it uses resources from the main project.

This is what my problems tab says:
The container 'Library Projects' references non existing library 'C:\AndroidDev\workspace\FlashcardsCommon\bin\flashcardscommon.jar'
Type: Build Path Problem

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this thread:

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=21031

1. It generally helps to go to Window -> Preferences -> General ->
   Workspace and check "Refresh automatically".  Then try clean
   building your projects incrementally.
2. You may also have to remove the source inclusions that represented
   your library dependencies manually.  You will find that ADT 14 and
   15 are very frustrating to work with when you have library projects.
   It requires frequent manual cleans of libraries AND their dependent
   projects to make changes to library projects effective.

Altogether, good effort by Google, but it's a bit buggy.

Another similar thread:

[Cannot build library dependent project after update to ADT 14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7843429/cannot-build-library-dependent-project-after-update-to-adt-14)

Comment: Where can I see my ADT version? Is there any big benefit from this update? Seems like a good idea to revert to my previous setup and wait for this to be solved.

Comment: Go to Help -> About Eclipse and click on the Android looking icon.  If you are going to try to revert, you are best off starting with a fresh Eclipse install; it isn't easy.

Comment: Google's heart was in the right place, since the source-inclusion-for-library-projects strategy was fairly brittle.  Unfortunately, it just wasn't well tested enough.  There are some nice improvements to LogCat in ADT 14+, however.

Comment: I have about 6 apps (flashcards of different subjects) that all use the same library project for 99% of the code, so as you can see this bug really affects me. Is this issue present since ADT 14? So I would have to reinstall Eclipse and ADT 13, right? (don't remember what I had before updating) Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes, the problems really all started with ADT 14, and they fixed some of it in 15.  Still not really great.

Comment: Just in case someone else wants to revert back to a previous ADT, there is a way to do so (easily?). Go to Eclipse, Help menu, About Eclipse, Installation Details button, Installation History, and there you can revert to a previous configuration. I have still to do this to see if it actually works. It does show I previously had ADT 12.0.0.

Comment: The rollback didn't work out so good. So I redownloaded Eclipse and the ADT, but I can't figure out how to install the ADT from my file and not a download. Is there any site that describes this? Googled with no luck.